# Arduino working with char* of unknown size

Tags: arrays, string, arduino, char

I have a problem in which I have to work with an array of char and modify it on the fly. For example, I receive a string via Serial or whatever, and I need that char array to be te same as the String.

Example:

```
char* pepe = "whatever";
String stringReceived = "AnyStringOfUnknownSize";
```

I tried:

```
For(int i=0; i< stringReceived.lenght(); i++){
pepe[i] = stringReceived.charAt(0);
}
```

But it only works if the string is the same size as the char*, if it is not it works unproperly (leaving extra chars or things like that). I did not find any way to modify the length of the char array. And there is no much info about char* in arduino.

Any help will be really apreciated.

Comment: Make sure you are putting a null terminator ('\0') at the end.

Comment: You've been very helpful, thanks a lot, please write this comment as an answer so I can select it as the solving answer. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are putting a null terminator ('\0') at the end.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(){

  //your initial data
  char pepe[100];
  std::string stringReceived = "AnyStringOfUnknownSize";

  //iterate over each character and add it to the char array
  for (int i = 0; i < stringReceived.length(); ++i){
    pepe[i] = stringReceived.at(i);
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
  }

  //add the null terminator at the end
  pepe[stringReceived.length()] = '\0';

  //print the copied string
  printf("%s\n",pepe);
}
```

Alternatively, you should consider using [strcpy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy)

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main(){

  //your initial data
  char pepe[100];
  std::string stringReceived = "AnyStringOfUnknownSize";

  //copy the string to the char array
  std::strcpy(pepe,stringReceived.c_str());

  //print the copied string
  printf("%s\n",pepe);
}
```

Comment: Note that AVR Arduinos [don't actually have](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/modules.html) the C++ headers available.